# How to search exact text in nested document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index like this,

```
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "URpYIFBAQRiPPu1BFOZiQg",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {

           "currency": null,
           "colors": [],
           "api": 1,
           "sku": 9999227900050002,               
           "category_path": [
              {
                 "id": "cat00000",
                 "name": "B1"
              },
              {
                 "id": "abcat0400000",
                 "name": "Cameras & Camcorders"
              },
              {
                 "id": "abcat0401000",
                 "name": "Digital Cameras"
              },
              {
                 "id": "abcat0401005",
                 "name": "Digital SLR Cameras"
              },
              {
                 "id": "pcmcat180400050006",
                 "name": "DSLR Package Deals"
              }
           ],
           "price": 1034.99,              
           "status": 1,
           "description": null,               
        }
```

And i want to search only exact text ["Camcorders"] in category_path field.
I did some match query, but it search all the products which has "Camcorders" as a part of the text. Can some one help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: An example of the search query you tried would be nice. Then its easier to go from there. Usually you should be good with a term query though, which looks for exact matches based on your analyzer: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html. Combine this with a nested query and you are good: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add one more nested field `raw_name` with `not_analyzed` analyzer and match against it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes without map not_analyzed it wont get result

Answer (score 1):

To search in nested field use like following query

```
 {
  "query": {
    "term": {
       "category_path.name": {
          "value": "b1"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: If it works.. accept the answer and help others to find answers...!